# How to resolve 'element basis is not included in backing stream'?

Tags: accurev

I am trying to promote a file from my parent stream to the backing stream but I got this error,

"Element basis is not included in backing stream:"

Any help is appreciated, on how to resolve this issue'element basis is not included in backing stream'

Answer (score 1):

From the GUI’s Stream Browser, right click on the parent stream of the workspace you’re trying to promote from; select “Show Active Issues.” In the resulting window/tab select the “Unaffiliated Change” and in the bottom panel will be the files that are not affiliated with an AccuRev Issue.  For the files that you are trying to promote you will need to affiliate them with an Issue.  Select the files and then right click and “Send to Issue.” You can use the same Issue, the original Issue they were attached to or even a “clean-up” Issue.

The files become unaffiliated when they are promoted to a Dynamic Stream and then someone removes the file from the Issue. Now the files have (member) status on the stream, but are not associated with an Issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an excluded rule set on the parent stream for this file or directory path?

If so, you will need to include the file or path to the file for the promote to work.